# Can't get FontAwesome icons to center within span parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I've tried everything, but I can't see what's causing the problem. I'd like my icons to center in the span class (so all my icons look centered and not random/messy).

Here's my fiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fbuww2hr/1/
```

Main part of the html that's causing trouble:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fornavn" aria-label="Fornavn">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text border-right-0" style="text-align: center; background-color: white !important">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile"></i>
            </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-left-0" placeholder="Efternavn" aria-label="Efternavn">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.input-group-text {
    width: 45px;
}
```

And then add `mx-auto` to your font awesome element like so:

```
<span class="input-group-text">
    <i class="far fa-envelope mx-auto"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Why does mx-auto work but not text-align: center? I've read a dozen stackoverflow posts about issues such as mine, but none suggested mx-auto

Comment: @Fross Because mx-auto sets the left and right margins to auto, centering the element, rather than centering text.

Answer (score 0):

Add `justify-content: center;` to this element .

```
<span class="input-group-text border-right-0" style="text-align: center; background-color: white !important"> 
    <i class="fas fa-mobile"></i> 
</span>
```